# Difficulty in Active records syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, procedure, records

I am trying to switch from a stored procedure in mysql to Active Records (Rails). 
I am confused about the syntax for active records.

For example my mysql stored procedure is as follows:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE test
    (IN test_number INT, IN test_id INT, IN test_begin_date DATETIME)
```

What will be the corresponding syntax in active records.???

Comment: I wanna know the syntax for Active Records

Comment: There isn't any specific support for calling stored procedures in rails (beyond the ability to execute arbitrary sql) if that's what you're asking

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How to not use the stored proc and create a method that is the equivalent of the stored proc code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ActiveRecord syntax for that. "Active Record facilitates the creation and use of business objects whose data requires persistent storage to a database. It is an implementation of the Active Record pattern which itself is a description of an Object Relational Mapping system." - from [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Still, ActiveRecord allows you you to execute any SQL using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(...)
```